# Error while saving SXA page from Experience Editor

Tags: sxa, sitecore-api

I am trying to save the page after doing edits in SXA page from Experience editor and getting below error every time. This is occuring only for this page. In network tab, the response for CallServerSavePipeline request is having error. Not sure what could be the reason!

**Error in the page**

[image]

**Network tab while saving the page**

[image]

**Response for CallServerSavePipeline request**

[image]

Adding screenshot of the logs

[image]

**Error in Logs**

> 14256 00:33:40 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing
>   the subscribers to the 'item:saving' event. Exception[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQVER.png):
>   System.NullReferenceException  Message[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQVER.png): Object reference not set to
>   an instance of an object.  Source[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQVER.png): Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites
>   at
>   Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.EventHandlers.SaveCompositeItems.UpdateDatasourceTokens(Item
>   compositeDatasourceChild, IEnumerable`1 renderings, Item currentItem) 
>   at
>   Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.EventHandlers.SaveCompositeItems.PropagateLayoutChanges(Item
>   item)    at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String
>   eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
>
> 14256 00:33:40 ERROR Failed to save the item. Item ID:
>   {43F3C3B3-C7A8-46FD-B815-6B25EDCBEE40}, database: master Exception:
>   System.AggregateException Message: One or more exceptions occurred
>   while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saving' event. Source:
>   Sitecore.Kernel    at
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName,
>   Object[] parameters, EventResult result)    at
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[]
>   parameters)    at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaving(Object sender,
>   ItemSavingEventArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.DataEngine_ItemSaving(Object sender,
>   ExecutingEventArgs`1 e)    at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object
>   sender, TEventArgs e)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1
>   handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseExecuting(Boolean&
>   cancelled)    at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.CanExecute()
>
>   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
>
> 14256 00:33:40 ERROR Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation. Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Source: mscorlib    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
>   Object[] parameters, Object obj)    at
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args,
>   Pipeline pipeline)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.Pipeline.Start(PipelineArgs args, Boolean atomic)
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.SaveItem.CallServerSavePipeline.ProcessRequest()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorRequest`1.Process(RequestArgs
>   requestArgs)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.AggregateException Message: One or more exceptions
>   occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saving' event.
>   Source: Sitecore.Kernel    at
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName,
>   Object[] parameters, EventResult result)    at
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[]
>   parameters)    at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaving(Object sender,
>   ItemSavingEventArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Events.Event.DataEngine_ItemSaving(Object sender,
>   ExecutingEventArgs`1 e)    at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object
>   sender, TEventArgs e)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1
>   handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseExecuting(Boolean&
>   cancelled)    at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.CanExecute()
>
>   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean
>   updateStatistics, Boolean silent)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics,
>   Boolean silent)    at Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.Save.Process(SaveArgs
>   args)

Comment: Please check in logs and add into your question detailed error message which I suppose you will find there

Comment: Please copy the text from error message into your question so it's indexed by search crawlers and easily found by others in the future

Answer (score 1):

Got the issue. One of the tab item is using query in the datasource field which is wrong. It is working as expected once the query is corrected in that field.
Thanks!!